# DOMNodeInserted event gets fire multiple times in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following little example:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', function (e)
{
    console.log('inserted');
});
```

When I now add an element via code like

```
$('body').append('<div></div>');
```

The event fires, everything is fine.

However, when I add a block of elements like

```
$('body').append('<div><strong></strong></div>');
```

the event fires for each element in the block I'm adding in the IE (so two times in this example). In other browsers it gets fired only once.

How can I work around this so that I only get one event call per code block?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution - but you could do something like:

```
$.fn.added = function()
{
    console.log('inserted');
};

$('body').append('<div></div>').added();
$('body').append('<div><strong></strong></div>').added();
```